# PC freeze when rendering/play games

Tags: graphics-card, freeze

as the title suggests my pc freezes when trying to play games. No BSOD, just freezes and I can't do anything but reset it by pressing the button on the case. At first I noticed this happening with the game Overwatch, everytime I launched that game it would freeze at moment when it loaded the menu background animation. In the beginning this wasn't happening very often but now it got worse, I also want to mention this freezing also happened in BIOS as well. My temperatures seem fine and I tried everything like clean re-installs. It's driving me crazy.

My specs are:

- Windows 10 Pro 64 bit
- Asus Sabertooth Z97 MARK 1
- Intel i7 4790k
- Asus STRIX GTX 970
- Kingston HyperX FURY 1600MHz DDR3 2x8GB
- EVGA SuperNOVA 750 G2 PSU

no overclocking.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this caused by my backup service using all my RAM and disk to backup. I stopped it and my games ran smoothly.

Open Task Manager and take a look at what other programs are running. Sort by CPU, disk, and memory usage. If something is hogging a resource you can look into killing it.